# can I call a HTTP endpoint from AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I know its not possible to call a HTTP api endpoint from a HTTPS website, 
I want to know if it is possible in lambda so i can call the http endpoint in lambda and call the lambda function to get the result of it

Comment: You're question is quite vague, but just to clarify do you mean you want to call an HTTP endpoint from inside your AWS lambda function, and then have the lambda function return the results from the HTTP request you had sent from the lambda? In essense: HTTP Endpoint <- Lambda Function <- Caller ?

Comment: @fixatd yes this is what i am hoping to do because i cant find any other way to make a http request from a htttps page

Comment: Yes, that's possible, however that would be somewhat the "ineffecient" way of doing things. It would be better to just have you're own Web Server do the call instead of calling a lambda function, or is that not possible in your current setup?

Comment: @fixatd is it possible to create a web server in a js file that is not node (front end)

Comment: Don't quite get your question, would probably best to add how your web pages are getting served.